# X (on Mint Debian, GeForce2 Integrated) is unstable after installing legacy nVidia drivers

Tags: linux, drivers, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card

This is a long story so I'll try to trim it down, please ask for any information.

This machine is running [Linux Mint Debian](http://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=88), it's an [ASUS A7N266-VM](http://www.unitycorp.co.jp/support/download/manual/a/a7n266_vm_e.pdf) with GeForce2 Integrated Graphics [NVCrush11] that is targeted by the [legacy drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-96.43.20-driver-all.html).

So, there I went to compile it. I booted into text mode, had the (.run) installer disable nouveau (which worked fine), rebooted (again in text mode), had the installer compile and set up the driver, and rebooted into text mode.

Suffice to say it was a mess of garbage, so I read the [manual](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86/96.43.20/README/index.html) (again), looking for what it could be. It says something about AGP, so I disabled AGP with `NvAGP` X server configuration option to 0, and while the garbage on the screen was less pronounced, it still looks like this:
[image: argh]
Some things fail to re-paint, others paint where they should not, and it starts getting worse after opening applications until X crashes and restarts.

So, I've started X with high log verbosity, but I still can't figure out the problem. Here's the [Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/ZekDvKYv), and here's the [xorg.conf](http://pastebin.com/6ydfCCTm).

**Edit:** After looking around, I've seen quite a lot of threads with problems on this drivers, and this graphics cards, (and nVidia in general) on Linux, just no fix! I'm still looking for a fix.

Please, help me find the problem! It will be very very appreciated :)

Comment: "[   149.657] (II) NVIDIA(0): Initialized GART." repeated many times - that looks very suspicious...

Comment: @pjc50 I guess so, but I've never looked at a good one, so I don't know how it looks. By the way, what does GART mean?

Comment: Google says "Graphics address remapping table" and that it's something to do with AGP. Don't actually know what it is myself.

Comment: @pjc50 Well, as said, I disabled AGP, or at least I've set the relevant option to disable it. Actually, I even used the `nvidia-xconfig` utility provided with the driver to set the flag, in the hopes that it did something different. AGP should be disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This makes it "work":

```
sudo nvidia-xconfig --no-render-accel --no-render-extension
```

But it's so bad it's not even worth it. Sorry nVidia folks, you suck at making a driver for your own board. I know it's an old board, but nouveau drivers are quite better.